# ¿Cómo puedo comparar el contenido entre un <p>Contenido</p>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

En mi caso necesito comparar un número con otro en una función y de acuerdo al resultado mostrar determinada imágen.

El problema es que es un número que me llega de un `_PLC_` y solo se muestra en html así `:="nombre_variable":` y lo inserto en un `<p>` así:

```
<p>:="nombre_variable</p>
```

Esto muestra el número que manda el `_PLC_`

Quiero extraerlo con alguna función en `_JS_` o lo que sea, quiero poder compararlo para tomar acciones dependiendo a este valor.

Por favor si alguien sabe del tema me puede dar una posible solución. 
Gracias =)

Comment: es dentro de una etiqueta de parrafo solo que no se mostró<p></p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes asignar una id a tu parrafo

```
<p id="valor">:="nombre_variable</p>
```

Y puedes obtenerlo desde JS

```
var valorPLC = $('#valor').text();
```

Y asi manejas el valor

Puedes compararlo mas o menos asi :

```
if (valorPLC === 'ejemplo')
```

Comment: y para comparar esa variable con una cadena o número ? perdona soy principiante en temas de desarrollo web

Comment: En mi respuesta ya se guarda en una variable que se llama `valorPLC`, en que otra variable quieres guardarlo?

Comment: si ya vi de hecho pero ahora entonces como la comparo con otro valor por favor

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda.